# add footer to FlowDocumentsdocuments

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I want to add footer to [FlowDocuments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.textalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in wpf. Please help me how to add?

Answer (score 4):

After you load an XAML file, you will get an IDocumentPaginatorSource object, from which you can get its DocumentPaginator.

You can wrapper around DocumentPaginator, overriding its GetPage method to add header, footer, or anything else like watermark.

For getting the code goto [Convert XAML Flow Document to XPS with Style](http://blogs.msdn.com/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

look at this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PimpedDocumentPaginator.aspx